# Conditional value using IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use an IF statement to conditional format a cell.  I am asking it to look for either an O or N/A in 7 different cells and if all seven have either of these populate active cell with O.  Note the O is not an actual O but a keystroke character used by my company.  represented by the U in the formula.  Right now the formula doesn't error out but it doesn't populate the new cell either.  This is the formula I came up with.

```
=IF(AND(OR(N9="Ù",N9="N/A"),OR(R9="Ù",R9="N/A"),OR(V9="Ù",V9="N/A"),OR(Z9="Ù",Z9="N/A"),OR(AD9="Ù",AD9="N/A"),OR(AH9="Ù",AH9="N/A"),OR(AL9="Ù",AL9="N/A")),"Ù","")
```

Comment: Have you tried making this work on the most basic level? Start off with just an `if` statement on one cell and see if it works with your unique keystroke in the company. If it works, then add the `OR` statement to it. See if it works. Then add the `AND` statement and 2 `OR` statements. If that works then you are all set to add the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an old fashioned [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) across the 25 columns and only accept results from columns on a stagger of 4.

[image: Staggered COUNT]

The formula in M9 is,

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(((N9:AL9="Ù")+(N9:AL9="n/a"))*(MOD(COLUMN(N:AL), 4)=2))=7, "Ù", "")
```

Counting every fourth column for either `Ù` or `n/a`, if the total count is 7 then display `Ù`. If not, display nothing.

Fill down as necessary.

You can get a little fancier by transposing a constant array of hte text values.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((N9:AL9=TRANSPOSE({"Ù","n/a"}))*NOT(MOD(COLUMN(N:AL)-2, 4)))=7, "Ù", "")
```

A cell outside of the stagger range can also be a primary decider.

```
=IF(OR(L9="no", SUMPRODUCT((N9:AL9=TRANSPOSE({"Ù","n/a"}))*NOT(MOD(COLUMN(N:AL)-2, 4)))=7), "Ù", "")
```

Comment: I tried this in another section and it doesn't work.  I changed the target cells and the offset and total cells but it won't return anything.  What did I mess up =IF(SUMPRODUCT(((N9:AM9="O")+(N9:AM9="N/A"))*(MOD(COLUMN(N:AM),5)=2))=6,"OK","")

Comment: Put `=MOD(COLUMN(N:AM),5)` under the first column you want data from and fill right. Does each of the columns you want return the same number? Is it a 2?

Comment: Then `MOD(COLUMN(N:AL), 4)=2` should be `MOD(COLUMN(N:AL), 4)=5`. The [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-0CAF2C6C-891D-4A0B-B618-3B0D60296809) is the remainder from a diovision operation. If your 'stagger' is regularly every 4 columns, then you can check the mod of the column number to see it it matches.

Comment: OK last question here.  Is it possible to add an or to this that if a cell outside the range of the last formula ="No" that I would also get the result "OK"  I have scoured everywhere and everything says combine the formulas.  But that doesn't seem to work I just end up with a "true" False" result.

Comment: Did you mean if any *one* cell is No then everything is OK or did you mean a No in one of the other cells can substitute for one of the seven {"Ù","n/a"} in the seven staggered cells?

Comment: A "No" in a cell not currently not called out in the formula. L9.  If it is a "No"  Then disregard everything and give OK.

Comment: I think I would just put that condition in with an OR function.

Comment: I hope you get this.  I have another IF sum product question.  Your help last time help me expand my understanding but I hit a wall again.  Similar situation as above but it won't work. =IF(SUMPRODUCT(((L9="No")+(N9:AM9="O")+(N9:AM9="N/A"))*(MOD(COLUMN(N:AM),5)=4))=6,"OK","") It won't return the OK when a No is present.

Comment: @DrewBoughton - This is too much for a comment. Can you start a new question? You can reference this q&a as well as provide new details.